# When User Not Found, Go To Page Not Found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a not found page when a user not found. When you enter the wrong username in the address bar it will go to a not found page. The code I got isn't working but it working when enter the right username.

```
    <? session_start();
include "includes/dbconfig.php";



// CHANGE USERNAME TO LOWERCASE
$username = strtolower($_GET[user]);

// CHECK IF THE USER EXISTS 
$check_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");


// WHILE LOOP THRU DATABASE
while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_user)) {

// GET FIELD HIDDENAUTH
$thepowers = $display['hiddenauth'];

// GET THE POWERS TO SEE IF DJ OR NOT
if ($thepowers == "no") {
include "profile_members.php";
} else {


// IF NO HIDDENAUTH FOUND REDIRECT TO ERROR PAGE
header("Location: notfound.php");
exit();
}}
?>
```

The ..htaccess has this...

```
    RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks All
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/uploads_user/(.*)$ profiles/1/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like it should redirect for people with a hiddenauth of anything other than 'no'. It won't redirect when the username isn't found in the database. What isn't working?

Comment: You need to add [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) above [`session_start();`](http://www.php.net/session_start) for one thing, if you're going to use [`header()`](http://www.php.net/header)

Comment: I've added that Fred still no luck, if you go on [link]http://vcasts.tv/itsmax[/link] that works but enter a different one IE, http://vcasts.tv/hjgf it just blank.

Comment: You should not _redirect_ to the 404 page anyway – because that way clients (including search engine crawlers) will not know that the resource was not found. Output a 404 status code and the accompanying 404 document from within your script instead.

Comment: It's not meant to be an 404 page, it meant to go to a notfound.php